# Google's zxing (Zebra Crossing) barcode library's BitMatrix not where it's supposed to be

Tags: java, barcode, classnotfoundexception, zxing

The javadoc lists the BitMatrix class as being in `com.google.zxing.common`.

```
com.google.zxing.common 
Class BitMatrix

java.lang.Object
  com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix
```

But after I compile the core jar, it is in `com.google.zxing.qrcode.encoder`.

```
$ jar tvf core.jar | grep ByteMatrix
  1851 Thu Apr 21 18:01:14 PDT 2011 com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder/ByteMatrix.class
```

So I am getting compile errors.

```
[javac] Compiling 1 source file to /home/dacracot/Code/QRtest/tmp/classes
[javac] /home/dacracot/Code/QRtest/src/QRtest.java:14: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : class ByteMatrix
[javac] location: package com.google.zxing.common
[javac] import com.google.zxing.common.ByteMatrix;
[javac]                               ^
```

What gives? Using version 1.6.

Comment: So, the javadoc's wrong. Use the correct package name. Or perhaps the doc refers to an older version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `BitMatrix`, but then you grep for `ByteMatrix`. These are different classes. `ByteMatrix` is indeed only a support class for that encoder. Both are in the same respective places in the source and jar, and both are where they are intended to be.